# Optimizing hierarchical data based category table

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a category table based on this tutorial: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

The structure of the table is really simple:

```
id, lft, rgt
```

And this is the query:

```
SELECT c . *, (COUNT(DISTINCT(parent.id))) AS level
FROM categories AS parent, categories AS c
WHERE c.lft
BETWEEN parent.lft
AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.lft
```

As you can see the same table is used twice. There's a between clause and it has group by and order by.

I'm not sure at all how I should optimize this.

When using EXPLAIN on this I get:

```
Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: Let's see the entire `EXPLAIN`.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Run this:  `FLUSH STATUS; SELECT ...; SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';` and tell us how many rows in the table and how many rows in the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to try the method with a [closure table](https://kylecordes.com/2008/transitive-closure) - much simpler idea and much more readable queries.
You will need a trigger for INSERT/UPDATE plus the closure table holding all possible relationships between a parent and its children/grandchildren/grand-grandchildren ....
Also include the nodes themselves (with DEPTH = 0)

```
+-------------+----------+-------+
| ancestor_id | child_id | depth |
+-------------+----------+-------+
```